# Adding a constant to an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution

Let $θ$ be an unknown constant. Let $W_1,…,W_n$ be independent exponential random variables each with parameter 1. Let $X_i=θ+W_i$.

How do I calculate the distribution of $X_1$, given θ? Notice that I don't look for a conditional probability here since $θ$ is a constant. My guess is that $P_X(x;θ)= e^{-(x_1-θ)}$ but I'm not sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. To prove it, just plug it in the definition of cdf:

$$P(X_i \le x) = P(W_i \le x - \theta_i) =( 1 - e^{-(x - \theta_i)})1_{x \ge \theta_i}$$

If you want the pdf you can take the derivative to get

$$f_{X_i}(x) = e^{-(x-\theta_i)}1_{x \ge \theta_i}$$

Comment: Note the CDF has a $1-$ in it...

Comment: @Ian True, thanks! I was just editing :)

Comment: Thank you both. Can you also help me understand how can I find the value of θ that maximizes this expression w.r.t $x_1$?

Comment: @Floyd It's not clear to me what you mean. You want to find $\theta_i$ such that $f_{X_i}(x)$ is maximized, considering $x$ constant? In that case it's simply $\theta_i = x$ but I doubt that's what you mean.

Comment: @Ant Sorry for the ambiguity. I am just trying to calculate the maximum likelihood estimation for θ, based on observations $x_1,...,x_n$. Given that for the first observation $θ=x_1$ as you noted, I think that considering a sequence of all observations $θ=(x_1+...+x_n)/n$ but again I am not so sure. I would prefer a clue rather a clear solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @Floyd For that you have to write the pdf of the joint distribution (since they are independent is the product of the pdf). After that, take the logarithm to make your life easier and solve for $\theta$ as you would with any other function (take derivative, etc.). Pay attention to the boundary condition :)